# Pascal, convert string to palindrome

Tags: pascal

I must check if string can be changed to palindrome, fo example:

Input: AABBCC, ABCD

Output: Yes (ABCCBA), No

I come out with this code:

```
program test;
var
 x, y: string;
 i: integer;
begin
 readln(x);
  for i:= length(x) downto 1 do
  y := y + x[i];

 writeln(y);
 readln
end.
```

But this program only write text from back.

I will be gratefull for any answer

Comment: Can you think of a different *characterisation* of the strings that should return `true`?

Comment: racecar, for example accrrea

Comment: @MKLL: That's a different *example*, not a different *characterization*! :) Hint: what can you say about the *number of times* each character occurs in a string that should yield `true`?

Comment: Sorry, but  I'm from Poland and my eng is bot Perfect. I will try again

Comment: Now I see every char appears 2 times, sometimes with +1. Sorry for asking stupid questions

Comment: I will write code tomorrow, so somebody could use it

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is following:

1. Create array of integers indexed with characters like this: `chars:array['A'..'Z'] of integer`
2. Go through every char in string and increase its array element. For example string is 'ABBCBBA'. You would increase counter on 'A' twice, on 'C' once and on 'B' 4 times.
3. Then go through array and have one test boolean. If every index has value that is even or has ONLY one odd value, than string can be become palindrome. Else I cant become palindrome. Boolean starts as 'true' and will become false once you find odd value more than once. Above given example would return true because every character repeats even number of times, expect 'C' and 'C' is only uneven value. Something like 'ABBC' returns false.

Very simple algorithm. Good luck with implementation.

With this you can just output boolean value once you are done.